# Printf return value without return statement

Tags: c, return

Tried this on 3 different systems: CentOS, Ubuntu and Windows(MinGW) ; so I don't think this is an anomaly (undefined behavior)

```
int hello(void)
{
        (void)printf("HELLO WORLD\n");
}

int main(void)
{
        printf("%d\n",hello());
        return 0;
}
```

Output is:

> HELLO WORLD
>  12

It returns the correct value, even with different text. Any explanations?

Comment: Undefined behavior does not mean "always crash". It means that the compiler is free to implement it as it wishes, even if its implementation will cause the program to crash. I would guess that , since there is no return statement, the local variables (including the return value from printf) are overwritting the memory location that later would be read as a "return value" by the calling code. Make it return an `int*` and then more "fun" things will probably happen.

Comment: You could use the same version of gcc on each OS, there is still no guarantee of similar behaviour.  I just tried your code using gcc on OS X, and it prints zero, not 12.  Don't ever depend on undefined behaviour:  a different version of compiler or OS could alter it.  All you have found is a slightly entertaining coincidence, it is of no practical value.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it ***is*** [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If the ending `}` is reached, without a `return`, using the returned value is UB.

From `C11`, chapter §6.9.1, *Function definitions*

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
>   the caller, the behavior is undefined.

You should not really try to *judge* the UB by seeing the result of UB. It is, well, *undefined*, after all.

Comment: But, UB in three different system?

Comment: @anon_16 UB is specified by the language. it is _independent_ of the system. :-)

Comment: >But, UB in three different system?
The UB "happens" at compile-time: The code is written in a way that the language does not dictate *any* behaviour for the compiler to adhere to. So the compiler is free to do what he wants.
This also means that normally you will observe the same behaviour when using the same compiler even when on different systems - simply cause the compilers in general behave the same on all supported systems.

Answer (score 1):

When you build your code, you may get a warning:

```
warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

In function

```
int hello(void)
{
    (void)printf("HELLO WORLD\n");
}
```

Because of no `return` statement. That's why you will get [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 1):

While everyone points out the entire business is undefined behaviour, only one person answered to the actual question. However, there question is even more wrong and for some reason nobody tackles it.

> Tried this on 3 different systems: CentOS, Ubuntu and Windows(MinGW) ; so I don't think this is an anomaly (undefined behavior)

This reasoning is seriously flawed (no amount of systems you test can tell you whether this is defined or not). Not only that, your testing was clearly superficial. On my system compiling the code with -O2 suddenly makes it print 0, and likely same things will happen on your system.

The reason it could have worked by *accident* is that on your system return value is kept in EAX which was not modified after return to main() and the compiler emitted code which moves the value from EAX to the first argument of another printf.

As was noted earlier and demonstrated with -O2 failure, this cannot be relied upon.

Finally a sentence which is even more wrong:

> It returns the correct value, even with different text. Any
>   explanations?

What?

Let's take a look at the function in question:

```
int hello(void)
{
        (void)printf("HELLO WORLD\n");
}
```

The function has no return statement, so whatever result you get is not "the correct value". In particular, you did not ask the language to return the value returned by printf. It so happened that in your testing you got the value returned by printf, but that's not what you asked for, hence it was not "correct" in any sense. Strictly speaking one could wonder if the return value of the function which was called last is guaranteed to be returned in such a case, but it was explained and demonstrated that no.

Answer (score 0):

12 is exactly the return value of the first printf.
Probably, the result of `printf("HELLO WORLD\n");` will be left on `EAX` register.

So, when second printf expect a return value it is the last returned value of a function(`EAX`).